# Pronterface not responding to 3D printer

Tags: python, printing, 3d

Every time I try to connect in Pronterface, I can tell something seems to be "retrying" to connect over and over. I get this error message when I close out of the program:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "wx\_core.pyc", line 14669, in <lambda>
  File "wx\_controls.pyc", line 1850, in AppendText
  File "encodings\cp1252.pyc", line 15, in decode
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 30: character maps to <undefined>
```

I've spent 5 hours adjusting the hardware's baud rates and com ports etc... I just can't figure this out. Any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: Can you show us line 14669 and line 1850?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting Baud rate as 115200. If it doesn't connect , press the reset button ..close Pronterface and reconnect. New version on Pronterface is also released try that it's better.